# Swift ios how to pass data to other view by pushing a page

Tags: ios, swift, navigation, view

When I use segue in navigating to the next view my code is working and it could pass the data between the views but the problem is that when I used the code below.

Code I use to navigate, when I used that code below to navigate the  `override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)`  which is down below is no longer working. Using this navigation data is no longer passing to next view. In using the code below

```
if let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ScoreViewController") as? ScoreViewController
{
    present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

This code is not working when a segue is used to pass data to next view

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let dist = segue.destination as? ScoreViewController {
            dist.kid_score = KidScore
            print("naka:" , dist.kid_score)

        }
    }
```

Is there another way we can pass data to next view?

Comment: What is `KidScore` here, an object or `Type`??

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to call the `prepare(for segue..)` function, then for navigate to other view you have to call it like this,

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Your_Segue_Identifier", sender: Your_data)
```

If you perform the above line, below function will be called,

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == Your_Identifier {
        let destination = segue.destination as! ScoreViewController
        destination.item = sender as! Your_Data
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Alternative way to pass data while pushing to another view controller.

```
let scoreVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Identifier") as! ScoreViewController
scoreVC.item = Your_Data
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(scoreVC, animated: true)
```

Hope you understand the answer and let me know in case of any queries.

Comment: btw sir after passing scoreVC.item = Your_Data , how i am going to access your data from the nextview ?

Comment: You need to create property in ScoreViewController

Comment: What is KidScore in this dist.kid_score = KidScore?

Comment: that is the score of the kid , KidScore is the data from 1st view and dsit_kidscore is on the next view.nvm mind the dist that is just a naming . i access it on the view using

Comment: if let scoretodisplay = kid_score {

Comment: then you can access kid_score in ScoreViewController

Answer (score 0):

If you want to navigate to `Controller` on StoryBoard with Identifier "ScoreViewController", then do this(this will applicable when you are trying to show one storyboard's ViewController to another storyboard ViewController -

```
   let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
   let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ScoreViewController") as! ScoreViewController
   self.present(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

**UPDATE-** For passing the data -

you can pass value using `struct` -
Create a class in the swift file created like bellow

```
    class StructOperation {
      struct yourGlovalVariable {
      static var userName = String();
     }
 }
```

Assing value to `static var userName` variable of `struct yourGlovalVariable` in `StructOperation` class from `firstViewController` like-

```
@IBAction func buttonnSend(_ sender: Any) {
    StructOperation.yourGlovalVariable.userName = "Akorn Durn Kurvirck";
   //Code Move to Second View Controller(first one- put it here)
 }
```

In your `secondViewController` view controller get value like bellow-

```
var username = StructOperation.yourGlovalVariable.userName;
```

Comment: its working but data is not passing to the next view

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data on next view using both way. 
First you need to define property in your next ViewController with name `kid_score` in your case. 
By presenting `ViewController` you can use given code:

```
if let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ScoreViewController") as? ScoreViewController
{
  vc.kid_score = KidScore
  present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

For second case, you need to add identifier to that `segue` and pass it in `performSegue(withIdentifier: "YourIdentifier", sender: self)` method. Your code for `prepare` is correct. Just check if you are able to print the value of `KidScore` because it is looking like a `Type`.